# How to store a private key in Azure Keyvault?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-cli, private-key

I am trying to store a private key as a secret in the Azure Keyvault through the Azure portal but when I retrieve the value, I see it's modified (additional spaces are added). I also tried to add the secret through the `az cli` as follows:

`$file = get-content C:\Dev\private.key`

`az keyvault secret set --name private_key --value $file --vault-name testing-kv`

But I encountered the following error:

`unrecognized arguments: MIIEXXXXXXX...` Only the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` part of the private key is recognized but the rest isn't.

I also looked at this post [Store Private Key into Azure KeyVault, value got changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959034/store-private-key-into-azure-keyvault-value-got-changed) and the solution indicates to convert the private key as a secure string and upload the encoded value to the key vault:

`$secretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString 'C:\Dev\private.key' -AsPlainText -Force`

`az keyvault secret set --name private_key --value $secretValue`

But this didn't work because it stores the string `[System.Secure.String]` in the keyvault.

How can I store this private key in its integrity into the keyvault?

Comment: can you try this command from here [KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/?view=azps-8.1.0#key_vault)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to run in Powershell:

`az login`

`az account set --subscription mysub`

Go to the folder where you have the private cert and type:

`az keyvault secret set --name mynewkey --vault-name test-kv --file .\private.key`

This command reads the private key from a file and stores it in the keyvault without any modification