# How to add private key in secret of azure key vault to ssh in azure virtual machine using azure bastion

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-bastion

How to add private key in secret of azure key vault to ssh in azure virtual machine using azure bastion?
I am trying to login a linux virtual machine using bastion and i want to put my .pem file in secret, but i am not able to it right.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this answer to add a private key to an Azure Key Vault.
[How to store a private key in Azure Keyvault?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72972375/17824927)

To summarize, run the following from powershell:

```
az login
az account set --subscription <subscriptionName>
az keyvault secret set --name <keyName> --vault-name <vaultName> --file <\path\to\key.pem>
```